# May i call service to service AWS Lambda directly in API Architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, microservices

This is the first time I use AWS Lambda as an API architecture. 
Because im trying to implement serverless. 
Let say, I have three microservices where all of the microservices hosted on AWS Lambda. 
And I use AWS API Gateway as router. I also implemented Jason web token in API Gateway.

This is the public URL that the frontend will use.

1. URL Routing API - https://mydomain.co/v1/lambda-service1
       Lambda REAL URL - https://cr7z0dds42.execute-api.ap-southeast-amazonaws.com/DEV/
2. URL Routing API - http://mydomain.co/v1/lambda-service2
       Lambda REAL URL - https://cr7z0ddgg2.execute-api.ap-southeast-amazonaws.com/DEV/
3. API Routing URL - http://mydomain.co/v1/lambda-service3
       Lambda REAL URL - https://cgf7z0ddgg2.execute-api.ap-southeast-amazonaws.com/DEV/

Basically, if I am currently my client / frontend, I want to call data from API number 1 by using TOKEN, i will use the API routing URL. 
But there are some cases that the API number 1 needs to call service number 2 before return to client / frontend. 
Currently what I do is call directly service number 2 via Lambda REAL URL, not API Routing URL from service number 1 without using TOKEN.

Is this justified?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your query correctly maybe below might assist.

Justification is mainly based on the scale you expect the app you are developing and also your organisation/architecture policies (you might want to enforce).

If tokens are used for all API calls and making it consistence will make it easy when a wider team of developers working on the project down the track. Also make it easy for troubleshooting, as the scope of each Lambda function (in/outs) logic is clear and consistent.

Also another thought is around cost, API calls does cost you at scale. So that should be taken in to consideration as well during architecture. But (in my opinion) consistency in the app call flow, for the savings it might give for traffic not hitting API gateway, where the call is made directly from Lambda to internal resources might be negligible.

Anyways some thoughts to consider.